# Unity3d. Overlay of clothes on a human model

Tags: unity, graphics, overlay, cloth

I have:

- Clothes model (jackets, shirts, sweater etc. with various
  sizes,colors)
- Human model with dynamic height, width, position

Need overlay the clothes' model onto a human model.

Variant with a skeleton and skin is not suitable because of different clothing options and there will be a lot of variations of the model.

Need a mathematical combination of the inside of the clothes model with the surface model of the human. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-InteractiveCloth.html ?

Comment: Do it with bones. When all the clothes are very different, you could have many bones which are only used by a few pieces of clothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is WAY outside the realm of an SE question (as far as getting code to do what you want) - This  in not something easily done. You may be able to find something on the asset store that will calculate this for you - but in most professional game there would be a different clothing model for each character model.

What you probably want to look into is UMA: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13930

You will need to adjust your code to fit - and probably make some changes to your models - but overall it will probably do what you are wanting and more... Plus it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Character Customization example project. You'll find it under Unity Technologies in the Asset Store. You'll need to merge the meshes into one at runtime so that your model only takes up one draw call.

Answer (score 0):

You could create animation in blender 3d and use the gravity mode on your clothes.
then import it to your game.